# In the mobile version, badges are aligned badly in the user cards

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, user-card

This is how the user card looks like in mobile theme of the site:

> [image]

Zoom in on the alignment:

> [image]

Should be moved to the right a bit.

Comment: So you have a gold badge, 3 silver ones, 31 bronze and 87 ninja badges. What is the problem?

Comment: Why zoom in about 1000 percent?

Comment: @PythonMaster I suspect that's the normal zoom level of the OP here. Saves the need for glasses. :-)

Comment: Good way to be near-sighted... Yeah, you would still need glasses

Comment: What OS/device (it may be specific to Android or Apple...) are you viewing this on?

Comment: @Werner This current screenshot is from Samsung Galaxy S5 in Chrome, if try on my Mac with Safari, it [looks even worse](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4NNDh.png).

Comment: Reproduced on Safari (on iPhone and on the desktop version after clicking *mobile*) and on Chrome (on iPhone and on the desktop again). The offset is clearly broken.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: it is a very ugly alignment issue on the *mobile web version*. This does look like a bug, it isn't minor. Mobile web browsers don't zoom like the desktop version does.

Comment: @SabreTooth: this is about the *mobile web version*. I can confirm the problem both in mobile Safari and in mobile Chrome on iPhone; the badge icons are clearly misaligned.

Comment: @Bart: the problem is than in the mobile web versions of this page badge icons are clearly badly placed. It is worse on iPhone mobile browsers than in this screenshot.

Comment: Hello close voter. You may not like a bug and/or a bug may be minor but that doesn't stop it from being a bug... this question is on-topic and, while not verbose, adequately explains what the author believes to be the issue.

Comment: Define "badly" and "a bit" because they look decent as-is

Comment: @MartijnPieters I totally missed that and the ultra huge image kind of distracted me from looking in the tags.

Comment: From a history of seeing these vague/obtuse titles in order to clickhole the bait it's no wonder everyone's all over the place, coupled with the sub-perfunctory body content, that's poor QA reporting

Comment: @ShadowWizard it took me a second to notice the tag too. The initial revision and previous posts did not help matters.

Comment: Vague, non-descriptive title before the edit and as @ShadowWizard stated, a huge image with freehand circles and arrows distracted me from the tags as well.

Comment: @SabreTooth true, it's like throwing a huge 1000px sign at your face and yelling "READ THIS!" :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard it is like a billboard with all shiny things - and the actual information in the corner in 5pt font

Comment: @MartijnPieters in my tongue in cheek comment I was actually trying to point out the issue and that it's a real one. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
<div class="user-details">
    <a href="/users/259214/nicael">nicael</a><br>
    <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score " dir="ltr">3,211</span><span title="3 gold badges"><span class="badge1">●</span><span class="badgecount">3</span></span><span title="31 silver badges"><span class="badge2">●</span><span class="badgecount">31</span></span><span title="88 bronze badges"><span class="badge3">●</span><span class="badgecount">88</span></span>
</div>
```

Eww. No spaces?

```
<div class="user-details">
    <a href="/users/259214/nicael">nicael</a><br>
    <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score " dir="ltr">3,211</span> <span title="3 gold badges"><span class="badge1">●</span><span class="badgecount">3</span></span> <span title="31 silver badges"><span class="badge2">●</span><span class="badgecount">31</span></span> <span title="88 bronze badges"><span class="badge3">●</span><span class="badgecount">88</span></span>
</div>
```

In all.css:1:769, `width: 14px` should be `width: 8px`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is supposed to be like that. Up close like that, you can see the "major" spaces between the badge icon and the amount of that type of badge. But from far away, like default size on a computer, it looks completely normal. Yet on the mobile version, it's chaos.

I say that this should be implied. If it wasn't, from a regular size text (default size), it would look really weird. Ewww. Anyways, it should look like this:
[image]

Comment: The bug report is for the **mobile web** version of the page. You are using the desktop rendering.